# selenium with headless not working, but without code work properly

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, ssl, http2

```
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}') # optional
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, seleniumwire_options={'custom_headers': headers})
```

or

```
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
```

```
driver.get('https://www.singaporeair.com/kfLogin.form')
```

looks like error with (ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR/SSL certificate)

i tryed:

1. proxy
2. firefox (ssl certificate) crash on 2-nd page(when i try to press button login)
3. go through requests

So question is is that possible to pass it, and what i'm missing.